# How to copy article from database in joomla?

Tags: joomla-3.x, articles, database

When i copy row of **joomla_content** in database, that article show in articles component in management but not showing it in feature page(home).
except *id* all columns are similar with orginal article.  notice article is published and my homepage show feature articles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to also add a record to joomla_content_frontpage. With the ordering its easiest to do this in the frontpage manager, but if you need to do it programatically, you need to check where you want it in the order and change other items around accordingly